# Threads in java not running concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having a problem with multi-threading in Java. I need to compare a large list of names to itself (to find near-duplicates).

I've split up the work into 4 different threads, each comparing 1/4 of the list to the complete list. I use the same class for all 4 threads.

When I look at the thread monitor I see that they are not really running concurrently, they are active one after another.

what could be the problem?

This is the run-method of my thread-class:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            s = settings.conn.createStatement();
            JaroWinklerDistance jw = JaroWinklerDistance.JARO_WINKLER_DISTANCE;

        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < allNames.size(); j++) {
                if (j % 250 == 0) {
                }
                double proximity = jw.proximity(names.get(i), allNames.get(j));
                if (proximity > Double.parseDouble(settings.properties.getProperty("distanceTreshold")) && proximity < 1.00) {
                    if (names.get(i).length() > allNames.get(j).length()) {
                        substituteName(allNames.get(j), names.get(i));
                        allNames.remove(allNames.get(j));
                    } else {
                        substituteName(names.get(i), allNames.get(j));
                        names.remove(names.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
}
```

The substituteName-method executes an SQL-query that updates the records.

The threads are created as follows:

```
settings.getAllNames();
        int size = settings.allNames.size();
        int rest = size % 4;
        int groupSize = (size-rest) / 4;

        GroupNormalizer a = new GroupNormalizer(settings.allNames, new ArrayList<String>(settings.allNames.subList(0, groupSize)));
        GroupNormalizer b = new GroupNormalizer(settings.allNames, new ArrayList<String>(settings.allNames.subList(groupSize, (groupSize*2))));
        GroupNormalizer c = new GroupNormalizer(settings.allNames, new ArrayList<String>(settings.allNames.subList((groupSize * 2), (groupSize * 3))));
        GroupNormalizer d = new GroupNormalizer(settings.allNames, new ArrayList<String>(settings.allNames.subList((groupSize * 3), (groupSize*4 + rest))));
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
        d.start();
```

**EDIT:** all 4 threads alternate a lot between running and monitor (blocked)-status

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: Some code would be nice to analyse what may be wrong.

Comment: I'm using a quad core. The thread-class compares part of the large list. If it finds a near-duplicate it updates the database-records accordingly

Comment: maybe you give us a bit of source code where you create and start the threads?

Comment: Do you have some kind of locking mechanism in the threads?

Comment: In all likelihood you are using some classes that have internal synchronizatio, but it's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Can't tell without a little bit of code, but my guess: aren't you calling `Thread.run()` instead of `Thread.start()`?

Comment: sorry, I added the source code.

Comment: Set the equal priority between 1-5 and check

Comment: These four threads should have the same priority so I don't really see a point in changing it, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Ofcourse yes. But if you give some high priority it may work. That was my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm it look like this line is causing synchronization lockup:

```
if (proximity > Double.parseDouble(settings.properties.getProperty("distanceTreshold")) && proximity < 1.00)
```

try to pull the Double.parseDouble out of the loop since everything in there looks kind of constant to me.

Seems like the settings object is blocking ob access and in this way slowing you down.

Also it looks like you are accessing a DB during your claculation (catching SQLEx), this will slow you down by a very large factor. Try to separate read and write from the claculation process.

Comment: I did what you suggested and discovered that multiple threads were accessing the settings.properties file. I fixed that and now it looks better.

Comment: I also seperated the calculation from the read/write and now they are running perfecly at the same time (they were always waiting to access the database)

Answer (score 3):

[Executor Framework](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools) (thread pools) to the rescue!

> Thread pools manage a pool of worker threads. The thread pools
>   contains a work queue which holds tasks waiting to get executed.

Comment: I had this before, but I got the same results. what I did was
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    es.submit(new Thread..)

Comment: U sure it is not one-core-celeron?

Comment: Intel Core i7-2670QM @ 2.20GHz with 8 GB memory

Answer (score 1):

Try [ForkJoin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with using Double.parseDouble in Java from multiple threads concurrently. The method it uses internally to do the parsing is synchronized, so if you have a lot of threads calling it at the same time, the threads end up blocking.

This should be fixed in Java 8.

(see Java bug report JI-9004591 - "Monitor contention when calling Double.parseDouble from multiple threads" - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7032154 )

I suspect this is the reason why the change made in the accepted answer (moving the Double.parseDouble out) improved performance.